# Ошибка "Invalid image type"

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, страница-учётной-записи

Выкидывает ошибку при заполнении графы "редактировать профиль".
И, соответственно, данная ошибка не сохраняет информацию в заполненных полях.
В чем причина?

Comment: по поводу PS: [Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1)

Comment: @Grundy, да спасибо, я уже догадался букв добавить) Как с заполнением профиля быть? И фото уже добавил - все равно предупреждение выскакивает...

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы загружаете изображение недопустимого формата.

Comment: Возможно, но почему не написать о том, какой формат допустим? У меня обычный jpeg, почему не написать о разрешении или весе файла если дело в этом?

Comment: Попробовал посохранять ваш профиль без изменений. Один раз воспроизвелась ошибка, после переключения картинки на граватар и обратно больше не воспроизводится. Проверьте пожалуйста сейчас.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, теперь данные сохранились, спасибо. Баг?

Comment: @PrinceOFF похоже на баг при первоначальном добавлении картинки, там ссылка на imgur немного отличалась. Сделаю ещё несколько попыток воспроизвести, не меняя текста, ок?

Comment: Похоже, у вас проблема решена, а для разработчиков я собрал некоторые данные в ответе. Пишите, если ещё раз воспроизведётся.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я вижу по логам, первоначально была добавлена картинка `https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.jpg`. Профиль был сохранен и картинка отображалась корректно, но дальнейшие попытки сохранения профиля приводили к ошибке.

В отправляемом при нажатии на синюю кнопку POST-запросе была строка

```
ProfileImageUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.jpg
```

Я переставил картинку на идентикон и обратно, после чего сохранил. В новом, успешном POST-запросе на том же месте было:

```
ProfileImageUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.jpg?s=128&g=1
```

Вероятно, не хватало параметров `?s=128&g=1`, задающих размер картинки.

В моем профиле первоначально тоже была добавлена картинка без этих параметров, однако ошибка не воспроизводилась. Возможно, воспроизводится только при первом добавлении картинки и/или только при первом редактировании информации.

---

Что подозрительно: на странице редактирования профиля данного пользователя я вижу идентикон и две одинаковых картинки (должна быть одна).  При нажатии на "Изменить изображение" GET-запрос на `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/popup/change-picture/216568?_=123456`возвращает следующую структуру. (Все потенциально-личные детали я заменил на `abcdef` и `123456`).

Зелёная галочка `<span style="display: inline;" class="badge-earned-check"></span>` первоначально есть только на одной картинке, но если выбрать любую из них, то в следующий раз покажется меню с двумя картинками:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на странную конструкцию `?s=128&g=1?s=42&g=1`. Выглядит как будто добавление параметров к URL произошло два раза.

```
<script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/image-upload.ru.js?v=abcdef"></script>


<div class="popup profile-picture-popup">
    <h2>Изменить изображение</h2>
    <hr />

        <a class="avatar-change" data-profile-type="Imgur">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.jpg?s=128&g=1?s=42&g=1" />
            <span class="avatar-description">Загруженное изображение</span>
            <span class="badge-earned-check"></span>
        </a>
        <hr />
        <a class="avatar-change" data-profile-type="Imgur">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.jpg?s=42&g=1" />
            <span class="avatar-description">Загруженное изображение</span>
            <span class="badge-earned-check"></span>
        </a>
        <hr />
        <a class="avatar-change" data-profile-type="GravatarIdenticon">
            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/abcdef?s=60&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
            <span class="avatar-description">Идентикон</span>
            <span class="badge-earned-check"></span>
        </a>
        <hr />
    <a id="profile-picture-cancel" href="#">отмена</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему "подозрительно"? ) Сайт либо работает верно, либо нет. Значит есть определенные проблемы с работой.

Comment: @PrinceOFF "подозрительно" означает "разработчики, копайте в этом направлении" ))

Comment: @PrinceOFF можно я сделаю и опубликую скриншот из меню выбора картинки в вашем профиле?

Comment: когда мне задают "такой" вопрос я сразу вхожу в состояние легкой паники)) Можно, наверное, если там нет ничего страшного)

Comment: @PrinceOFF только текущая картинка.

Comment: @PrinceOFF обновил. Просто всю информацию, которую видят только модераторы, раскрывать публике просто так нельзя. Поэтому спрашиваю отдельно. )

Comment: Окей, спасибо за детальное описание. Я посмотрю, что там сломалось.

Comment: @AdamLear посмотрели? :)